# What are the differences between mixed data, panel data and longitudinal data?

Tags: r, economics

I don't understand the differences between mixed data, panel data or longitudinal data. Recently, I am studying the boost technique and learning the `R` packages `GMMBoost`: Likelihood-based Boosting for Generalized mixed models. This package is working with
mixed data. I am not sure that this package is also useful for panel data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a popular question. Usually people in econometrics call repeated measures panel data, but people in biostatistics call it longitudinal data. The difference between the two can be, the observed time points for panel data may be fixed and common for all subjects (e.g. year 1, 2 and 3), but can be random (e.g. month 1 and 3 for subject 1, but month 2 and 5 for subject 2) for longitudinal data.

I have not heard about the term "mixed data", but "mixed model" refers to a model including fixed and random effects.